# how often should i refresh my cache?

Tags: ios, caching

I'm writing the cache for an iOS app right now. I'm wondering how often i should refresh my cache. to give a little background, it's a weight loss app. what i'm working on right now, specifically, is a list of recipes. I pull the list of recipes from the server and display it in a table view. Obviously, i was going to make the list refresh when you pull down on the view controller. My question is, should i have it refresh the list every x number of days? or should it refresh every time the app is reopened? the list isnt expected to change more than once every 1 - 2 weeks, if that often. the user can also add their own recipes, so it could potentially change more often than that. is there a specific industry standard or protocol to follow for how often the cache should be refreshed?

Comment: Time to learn one of the more famous [aphorisms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188587/cache-invalidationis-there-a-general-solution) in CS.

Comment: didnt see that. thats interesting. i see we have a cunnundrum. you want to have a piece of cake. cake is good. you love having cake. but if you eat the cake, you will no longer have it. and nobody else will share.

Comment: when user open your app , save the current time in user default. and when again user opens the app , check if your store date more then a threshold (1-2 week any thing you choose here.), then refresh it from backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you hook up your app with a Push Notification Service ? so incase there is a new recipe you could dispatch a push notification and when the user opens the app refresh your cache. That way you only refresh your cache when needed and also aids in better user experience. Here's a good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) on setting up a push notification service

Comment: good suggestion. +1 for suggesting http://www.raywenderlich.com/. they have some REALLY useful articles on iOS work