# The difference between Reactive and Functional-Reactive programming

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, paradigms, reactive-programming

I have been doing some research into reactive programming recently and I'm finding it hard to find a good description of the difference between Reactive and **Functional**-Reactive.

Is it simply that the reactive programming is implemented using functional methods/paradigms as opposed to using declarative or OO paradigms?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Functional Reactive Programming (FRP) is a specific programming model with a specific semantics.
(Actually, there are two variants, which are sometimes called "classic FRP" and "arrow FRP".)
I've given a summary in [an answer to "What is (functional) reactive programming?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028250/what-is-functional-reactive-programming/1030631#1030631).
As I said there, the two key properties for me have always been (a) precise & simple denotation and (b) continuous time.
I regret that this model came to be called "functional reactive programming", for a few reasons:

- That name omits "time", and time is central for me.
- The term "functional" has so little specific/clear meaning.
  I much prefer Peter Landin's suggested replacement "denotative".
  (See the quotes and reference in [this blog comment](http://conal.net/blog/posts/is-haskell-a-purely-functional-language/#comment-35882).)
- It's easy for people to incorrectly think they know what the term means because they know meanings (more or less) of each of the three words.

For descriptiveness & accuracy, I prefer the term "denotative continuous-time programming" (suggested by Jake McArthur in a conversation a while back) over "functional reactive programming".

I wrote a very short piece on the origin of FRP in the blog post [*Early inspirations and new directions in functional reactive programming*](http://conal.net/blog/posts/early-inspirations-and-new-directions-in-functional-reactive-programming/).

Answer (score 30):

FRP is a combination of Functional programming(programming paradigm built upon the idea of everything is a pure function) and reactive programming paradigm (built upon the idea that everything is a stream(observer and observable philosophy)). It is suppose to be the best of both the worlds.

The definition of both give a more clear distinction between the two.

Comment: great overview :)

Comment: Could you go into more depth? I like your explanation, but when I use reactiveX (e.g. RxJava), I am reactive but not necessarily functional? Because within the reactive functions (chain) I can still have side effects or be non-idempotent (not functional).

Comment: What you assume is correct @BenButterworth  Using RxJava or for that matter any reactive library does not guarantee functional behavior. It is the developer's duty to ensure no side effects.