# Is AngularJS Functional Reactive Programming?

Tags: angularjs, functional-programming, frp

Every time I see the phrase [Functional Reactive Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming) I realize that I don't understand what it is.  I then go back to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028250/what-is-functional-reactive-programming), think I understand what it is, and the cycle repeats later.

> Example isn't another way to teach, it is the only way to teach *-Albert Einstein*

Is Angular an example/implementation of FRP?  Why or why not?

Comment: If this question is too broad, then I don't see how you can ever ask anything about FRP without the same problem.

Comment: AngularJS is NOT a programming language, rather a Framework :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think it is. Angular is very much tied to states. In fact, if you watch a continuous function, you'll hit infinite recursion as the state is always dirty.

To make continuous functions work in the browser, the digest cycle needs to stop even when the state is dirty. Angular doesn't stop until the state is no longer dirty.

**EDIT**

Dart can be used for FRP though: http://victorsavkin.com/post/55007674849/functional-reactive-programming-in-dart

Comment: @tietyt Added a reference to Dart for FRP

Comment: It would be good to at least clarify for the op that although angular.js may not be fully FRP base on your assertions, it is at least reactive programming.

Comment: I disagree, so many frameworks have *something* reactive like angular.js to be meaningless.

Answer (score 5):

As John Tseng answered, AngularJS is NOT an example of FRP. You can, however, use FRP with AngularJS by using the [angular-bacon](https://github.com/lauripiispanen/angular-bacon) module.