# Which actual products (web, mobile apps, etc.) use bacon.js?

Tags: javascript, bacon.js

Have been reading about *Functional Reactive Programming* and bacon.js. I have some questions concerning its adoption:

1. I'm curious about which companies have used bacon.js or are considering its use in actual products? I found [this article](http://blog.flowdock.com/2013/01/22/functional-reactive-programming-with-bacon-js/) from Flowdock, but was unable to find other examples.
2. Are there more mature JavaScript FRP frameworks?

Thanks!

Comment: Guys, what do you think? Is this a question about programming problem?

Comment: There is [flapjax](http://www.flapjax-lang.org/), but it seems to be more academic.

Comment: @TomášZato I was unsure where to post this question. Could you help me on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far this is the answer I found to my question:

1. I tried several searches on this topic but was unable to find other examples (besides Flowdock) of current products using bacon.js. From [this survey](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/javascript_library/all) on JS libraries it seems like bacon.js is not very widely used as it is not even considered on the list.
2. On the way to search for other FRP frameworks I found there are libraries just for Reactive Programming (Although it sounds obvious, I was initially unaware of the difference between FRP and just RP. You can check [this](http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-JavaScript-library-for-functional-reactive-programming) on Quora). This is the list of **frameworks for FRP**:

   - [Bacon.js](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js)
   - [Kefir](http://pozadi.github.io/kefir/) (a Bacon clone with better performance)
   - [Flapjax](https://github.com/brownplt/flapjax/)
   - [Elm](http://engineering.prezi.com/blog/2013/05/21/elm-at-prezi/) ([Seems like](http://engineering.prezi.com/blog/2013/05/21/elm-at-prezi/) is developed by Prezi. Actually it is a language in itself which compiles to HTML, CSS and JS)

   This is the list of **RP frameworks**:

   - [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/) (Developed by Facebook & Instagram)
   - [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) (There is [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/) developed by Netflix)
   - [Ractive.js](http://www.ractivejs.org/) (Originally developed at theguardian.com)

Comment: For the difference between FRP and RP, you might check out [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1028250/1048572) as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

**m.verkkokauppa.com** uses Bacon at the moment of writing this. It is so awful that I wrote [an article about Bacon's lack of performance](http://codepen.io/Merri/blog/bacon-js-bus-and-the-bumpy-road). I wouldn't recommend anyone to use Bacon for anything serious.

I assume people who used it got excited about it initially a whole lot and now that they've seen what it is remain silent as they are shamed of ever getting excited about it. But that is just a guess and not based on any facts. The truth is there is very little anything on the web about Bacon so it is probably best to just ignore it.

Kefir seems like a better one if functional paradigm is close to somebody's heart, but I haven't used it yet to see whether it is really any good.

```
// This code here exists only because Stack Overflow requires me to have a code block
// when posting a link to codepen.io even if it really is just a blog post.
```