# What is Elm's Signal's (Conal's Behaviors's) equivalent in RX ? Does RX have such a concept at all?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, elm, sodium

I was watching [this](http://youtu.be/Agu6jipKfYw) video (see image below) and it made me wonder whether Elm's Signal is the same as Conal's [Behaviour](http://conal.net/papers/push-pull-frp/).

I think they are the same but I am not 100% sure. Are they the same?

Here are a few related questions:

1) What is a Elm's Signal (Conal's Behaviour) in RX ? Is there such a concept in RX at all? Perhaps ReplaySubject?

2) How can I turn an RX Observable into a Signal (Behaviour) in RX ?
In [Sodium](https://github.com/SodiumFRP/sodium) there is the hold function for this purpose.

3) What is RX's Observable ( AFAIK RX's Observable corresponds to Conal's Event ) in Elm? Is there such a thing in Elm?

Thanks for reading.

Here are the questions expressed in a table:

[image]

Snapshot from the Elm talk:

[image]

Comment: I think this whole thread worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028250/what-is-functional-reactive-programming
If you interested in short conclusion: "reactive" is a buzzword now. So it's mostly pointless to look for a common background behind libraries associated with it.

Comment: I disagree. Functional reactive programming is discovered, not invented, so there is a common background. See Blackheath's new book. Also the whole point of Elm author's talk is to categorize FRP systems: to see what is common, what is different and why.

Comment: I just contributed an answer to that thread, before you mentioned it.

Comment: so you could note that everyone there is talking about different things :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial answer :

Sodium author Stephen Blackheath writes :

> Elm is an example of a system that has one type Signal that combines
>   Stream and Cell.

Source:
https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/35274.page

A note on about Sodium's naming convention:

Sodium's Stream is Conal's Event and Sodium's Cell is Conal's Behaviour.

EDIT:

RX BehaviorSubject = Conal's Behavior.

RX Observable = Conal's Event.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to your question above is that potentially your initial assumptions are wrong. I believe that the observable sequence is (more) analogous to Behaviour and Signal (Vary over continuous time, can be/are infinite, synchronous by default). Conal seems to indicate that an Event is a specific state at a point in time, a "happening" e.g. "the event describing the first left-button press after time t0" [*1]

```
|Rx            |Conal   |ELM   |
|--------------|--------|------|
|T             |Event   | ?    |
|IObservable<T>|Behavior|Signal|
```

I believe that an Event in Conal's description is the actual value at a point in time. So be more specific, I think this is even more accurate

```
|Rx                         |Conal   |ELM   |
|---------------------------|--------|------|
|TimeStamp<T>               |Event   | ?    |
|ReplaySubject<TimeStamp<T>>|Behavior|Signal|
```

I believe that here a `ReplaySubject<TimeStamp<T>>` more closely represents a Behaviour as I understand it (contain state and time, can fetch value at a point in time). However as a `ReplaySubject` does not really allow you just pull the state from a point in time, they are not like-for-like. In my opinion, an EventStore is a closer match.

So to be clear, *in my understanding* an Observable Sequence (Rx `IObservable<T>`) and Conal's Behaviour share a similar definition up to a point. They both represent an ordered sequence of values over time. However in Rx, this is all an observable sequence is. Remembering that Rx is purely a library to allow you to query streams of events. There are some features that allow you to cache data (`Replay`/`Buffer`) or work with windows of data (`Window`/`GroupJoin`) and you can even enrich data with timestamps (`TimeStamp`/`TimeInterval`).

However where Conal's Behaviours diverge from Observable Sequences, is in it's features of persistence and historical querying. As I understand it, Conal's Behaviour in addition to Rx's features also specify that you are able to pluck a value of a sequence at any given point in time. For example with there was a price tick at time 00:00:01 of $1.23 and then another price tick at time 00:00:05 of $2.34, a consumer could ask for a value at time 00:00:02 and would be given back the value of $1.23 (the most recent value at the point in time).

```
time         [t1   ]  [t2]  [t3]  [t4]  [t5   ]
prices   ----[$1.23]--------------------[$2.34]--->

price@t2 -------------[$1.23]|
```

Rx doesn't provide any support for this, but one could go to great lengths to write custom operators to support this.

```
//A forced example of querying historical data.
// Be carefull as Replay() uses an unbounded buffer!
var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))
        .Timestamp()
        .Replay();
var connection = source.Connect();

var time2 = DateTimeOffset.Now+TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
var valueAtTime2 = source.TakeWhile(ts=>ts.Timestamp <= time2)
                         .LastAsync();

valueAtTime2.Dump();    //LinqPad feature to output the result
```

Systems that can (could?) support this kind of retrospective querying could be systems like CEP (Complex Event Processing) engines or EventStore style databases.

[*1]. http://conal.net/papers/icfp97/icfp97.pdf

Comment: Interesting point. I was thinking that values from Observables cannot be extracted at any given time only when the Observable fires. On the contrary, values from Behaviour can be extracted any time, independently when events are fired in the system. So I don't quite understand the analogy drawn between Observable and Behaviour? Observable is not a continous time concept. It only has values when events are fired. Other than that it is stateless. While Behaviour has a state always.

Comment: I am not saying Observable's are the same as Behaviours, hence my final comment regarding an EventStore being a closer match. As I understand it a Behaviour is an ordered sequence of values over time. This is also what an Rx Observable sequence is. However, Conal's Behaviour also has the concept of persistence and lookup over time. This is where Rx and Conal diverge.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Could you please explain this in more detail in your answer? Then this could be the accepted answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, what do you think about my edit ?

Comment: "So to be clear, in my understanding an Observable Sequence (Rx IObservable<T>) and Conal's Behaviour share a similar definition up to a point." Conceptually they are just the opposite IMHO. Observable is discrete while Behaviour is continuos. What do you think?

Comment: In other words, Observable forgets, BehaviourSubject remembers. I gave a talk on this two days ago (http://www.meetup.com/Helsinki-Functional-Reactive-Programming-Meetup/events/220820685/), I will post the video when it has been edited.

Comment: "Observable is discrete while Behaviour is continuous." Yes that seems to be one good differentiation. If I havn't already made it clear, I would add that Conal's Behaviour also implies state, where as by default Rx/IObservable doesn't, you have to add it yourself.