# Bacon.js: practical difference between a stream and a property

Tags: javascript, events, bacon.js

As a newcomer to bacon.js, I can't seem to understand the difference between an event stream and a property.

- Properties are built from streams (except properties built with `.constant`?)
- They have most methods in common
- Subscribing to them works in the same way

Could someone explain the differences and when to use which?

In the example below, `stream` and `property` have the exact same behaviour. I'm afraid I fail to see beyond this.

```
var stream = Bacon.sequentially(250, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
var property = stream.toProperty();

stream.onValue(function (val) {
    console.log("Stream", val);
});

property.onValue(function (val) {
    console.log("Property", val);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bacon.js *properties* are *Behaviours* in FRP literature, and *EventStreams* are just *Events*. They look very similar, but semantically they are very different.

Familiarise yourself with FRP concepts, by e.g. reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028250/what-is-functional-reactive-programming).

Comment: From http://blog.flowdock.com/2013/01/22/functional-reactive-programming-with-bacon-js/ : *"Property is used as an abstraction for a time-varying value. Properties are similar to EventStreams, but they also have the notion of current value. Most of the functionality is shared with EventStreams."* What is meant by "current value"? It doesn't seem that the property value can be read directly.

Comment: You cannot read the current value of Property (Behaviour), it's against the semantics. Behaviour is a time-varying value, but you cannot handle time explicitly. If we would give you ability to read *current* value, then right after you'll want to read *previous* value etc. In FRP you don't really need *current* value; e.g. if we show current time with `currentTime.assign(label, "text")`-  there we handle *all*  values universally, and the library takes care, that when `currentTime` changes, `label.text` is updated.

Comment: That's precisely how I figured things, but then why can't it be said that the eventStream has a current value too? Or is it that a property has *only* a current value, which differentiates it from a stream?

Comment: You can talk about the *last* event occurred in EventStream, but there are no *current*. The discrete-time FRP makes it too easy to think about implementation of things (yes, Property and EventStream could be implemented using similar lower-level primitives), not about their **semantics**. Read about continuos-time FRP: even you'll never need one, it will make distinction more clear. E.g. animations are continuos-time, but the real world restricts us, so we sample it say 60 times per second.

Comment: There are *previous* values if we consider sampled values, but inside the (continuos) system there aren't. The difference culminates in how we (can) combine Properties and Events, e.g. `animationProperty.sampledBy(renderTicksStream)`.