# ReactiveCocoa vs RxSwift - pros and cons?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactive-cocoa-3

So now with swift, the [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) people have rewritten it in version 3.0 for swift

Also, there's been another project spun up called [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift).

I wonder if people could add information about what the differences in design/api/philosophy of the two frameworks are (please, in the spirit of SO, stick to things which are true, rather than opinions about which is "best")

To get started, my initial impression from reading their ReadMe's is:

- As someone who is familiar with the "real" C# Rx from microsoft, RxSwift looks a lot more recognisable.
- ReactiveCococa seems to have gone off into its own space now, introducing new abstractions such as Signals vs SignalProducers and Lifting. On the one hand this seems to clarify some situations (what's a Hot vs Cold signal) but on the other hand this seems to increase the complexity of the framework a LOT

Comment: Your question specifically asks for "opinions". Could you please reword? I will gladly retract my close vote then.

Comment: You can get rid of "add their opinions", because the differences are facts, not opinions. Then you can like or dislike some features of RAC/RxSwift, but differences are crystal clear.

Comment: hahaha, good move regarding the "note to mods"!

Comment: If you truly believe that it's sufficient to simply state that _you think_ a question is on-topic, then by all means start a discussion on Meta about it to have it made policy. Until then, I'll have to continue judging a question by its contents. This _question_ is plainly asking for opinion, regardless of its popularity or the excellence of the answers. It's therefore off-topic.

Comment: Rename question: Difference between ReactiveCocoa and RxSwift. I think everything will become "fact", and this question is legacy.

Comment: Even the solution starts with "This is a very good question." :|

Comment: hahahha nice one

Comment: Moderation without consideration have killed more forums than we realise..

Answer (score 428, accepted):

This is a very good question. Comparing the two worlds is very hard. Rx is a port of what Reactive Extensions are in other languages like C#, Java or JS.

Reactive Cocoa was inspired by *Functional Reactive Programming*, but in the last months, has been also pointed as *inspired by Reactive Extensions* as well. The outcome is a framework that shares some things with Rx, but has names with origins in FRP.

The first thing to say is that neither RAC nor RxSwift are *Functional Reactive Programming* implementations, according to [Conal's definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1030631/253315) of the concept. From this point everything can be reduced to how each framework handles side effects and a few other components.

Let's talk about the community and *meta-tech* stuff:

- RAC is a 3 years old project, born in Objective-C later ported to Swift (with bridges) for the 3.0 release, after completely dropping the ongoing work on Objective-C.
- RxSwift is a few months old project and seems to have a momentum in the community right now. One thing that is important for RxSwift is that is under the [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/) organization and that all other implementations are working in the same way, learning how to deal with RxSwift will make working with Rx.Net, RxJava or RxJS a simple task and just a matter of language syntax. I could say that is based on the philosophy *learn once, apply everywhere*.

Now it's time for the tech stuff.

### Producing/Observing Entities

RAC 3.0 has 2 main entities, `Signal` and `SignalProducer`, the first one publishes events regardless a subscriber is attached or not, the second one requires a `start` to actually having signals/events produced. This design has been created to separate the tedious concept of hot and cold observables, that has been source of confusion for a lot of developers. This is why the **differences can be reduced to how they manage side effects**.

In RxSwift, `Signal` and `SignalProducer` translates to `Observable`, it could sound confusing, but these 2 entities are actually the same thing in the Rx world. A design with `Observable`s in RxSwift has to be created considering if they are hot or cold, it could sound as unnecessary complexity, but once you understood how they work (and again hot/cold/warm is just about the side effects while subscribing/observing) they can be tamed.

In both worlds, the concept of subscription is basically the same, there's one little difference that RAC introduced and is the `interruption` event when a `Signal` is disposed before the completion event has been sent.
To recap both have the following kind of events:

- `Next`, to compute the new received value
- `Error`, to compute an error and complete the stream, unsubscribing all the observers
- `Complete`, to mark the stream as completed unsubscribing all observers

RAC in addition has `interrupted` that is sent when a `Signal` is disposed before completing either correctly or with an error.

### Manually Writing

In RAC, `Signal`/`SignalProducer` are read-only entities, they can't be managed from outside, same thing is for `Observable` in RxSwift. To turn a `Signal`/`SignalProducer` into a write-able entity, you have to use the `pipe()` function to return a manually controlled item. On the Rx space, this is a different type called `Subject`.

If the read/write concept sounds unfamiliar, a nice analogy with `Future`/`Promise` can be made. A `Future` is a read-only placeholder, like `Signal`/`SignalProducer` and `Observable`, on the other hand, a `Promise` can be fulfilled manually, like for `pipe()` and `Subject`.

### Schedulers

This entity is pretty much similar in both worlds, same concepts, but RAC is serial-only, instead RxSwift features also concurrent schedulers.

### Composition

Composition is the key feature of Reactive Programming. Composing streams is the essence of both frameworks, in RxSwift they are also called *sequences*.

All the observable entities in RxSwift are of type `ObservableType`, so we compose instances of `Subject` and `Observable` with the same operators, without any extra concern.

On RAC space, `Signal` and `SignalProducer` are 2 different entities and we have to `lift` on `SignalProducer` to be able to compose what is produced with instances of `Signal`. The two entities have their own operators, so when you need to mix things, you have to make sure a certain operator is available, on the other side you forget about the hot/cold observables.

About this part, [Colin Eberhardt](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/04/28/reactive-cocoa-3-continued.html) summed it nicely:

> Looking at the current API the signal operations are mainly focussed on the ‘next’ event, allowing you to transform values, skip, delay, combine and observe on different threads. Whereas the signal producer API is mostly concerned with the signal lifecycle events (completed, error), with operations including then, flatMap, takeUntil and catch.

### Extra

RAC has also the concept of `Action` and `Property`, the former is a type to compute side effects, mainly relating to user interaction, the latter is interesting when observing a value to perform a task when the value has changed. In RxSwift the `Action` translates again into an `Observable`, this is nicely shown in `RxCocoa`, an integration of Rx primitives for both iOS and Mac. The RAC's `Property` can be translated into `Variable` (or `BehaviourSubject`) in RxSwift.

It's important to understand that `Property`/`Variable` is the way we have to bridge the imperative world to the declarative nature of Reactive Programming, so sometimes is a fundamental component when dealing with third party libraries or core functionalities of the iOS/Mac space.

### Conclusion

RAC and RxSwift are 2 complete different beasts, the former has a long history in the Cocoa space and a lot of contributors, the latter is fairly young, but relies on concepts that have been proven to be effective in other languages like Java, JS or .NET. The decision on which is better is on preference. RAC states that the separation of hot/cold observable was necessary and that is the core feature of the framework, RxSwift says that the unification of them is better than the separation, again it's just about how side effects are managed/performed.

RAC 3.0 seems to have introduced some unexpected complexity on top of the major goal of separating hot/cold observables, like the concept of interruption, splitting operators between 2 entities and introducing some imperative behaviour like `start` to begin producing signals. For some people these things can be a nice thing to have or even a killer feature, for some others they can be just unnecessary or even dangerous. Another thing to remember is that RAC is trying to keep up with Cocoa conventions as much as possible, so if you are an experienced Cocoa Dev, you **should** feel more comfortable to work with it rather than RxSwift.

RxSwift on the other hand lives with all the downsides like hot/cold observables, but also the good things, of Reactive Extensions. Moving from RxJS, RxJava or Rx.Net to RxSwift is a simple thing, all the concepts are the same, so this makes finding material pretty interesting, maybe the same problem you are facing now, has been solved by someone in RxJava and the solution can be reapplied taking in consideration the platform.

Which one has to be picked is definitely a matter of preference, from an objective perspective is impossible to tell which one is better. The only way is to fire Xcode and try both of them and pick the one that feels more comfortable to work with. They are 2 implementations of similar concepts, trying to achieve the same goal: simplifying software development.

Comment: This is a great explanation, @junior-b! It's also worth mentioning, however, that RAC encodes type information (including lack of errors thanks to `NoError`) in the stream types themselves: `Signal<T, E: ErrorType>` versus `Observable<T>`. This, as well as the hot/cold separation, provides an increased amount of information at compile time that you just don't have with `RxSwift`.

Comment: Hi @nachosoto, thanks for the kind word. I think the proposed addition wouldn't fit so well in a comparison on Reactive Programming. It's definitely a nice addition on the RAC's side, but for me RP is about simplifying data flow programming and important factors are: error handling, asynchronous computation, side effects management and composition. From a developer perspective seems a nice feature, this is for clarifying the error type on the code, it's not really improving the error handling aspect of the framework, this is, of course my humble opinion.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that as of now there is a lack of decent tutorials on RAC, however there are some great sample projects for RxSwift which was decisive for me.

Comment: ReactiveCocoa was good, until they introduced free functions, SignalProducer, generic with Error. I learn RxSwift and I get the same experience when working with RxKotlin, RxJS