# What is Denotational Semantics and type class morphisms in Reactive Functional Programming?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reactive-programming, reactive

When am reading the answer for Functional Reactive Programming @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/1030631/524723

Some of the terms seems weird to me to get understand

They are Denotational Semantics and Type Class Morphism

I have read few resource as below

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotational_semantics
2. http://conal.net/papers/type-class-morphisms/
3. http://conal.net/papers/push-pull-frp/

I am from JavaScript background and i am using redux and rxjs for achieving Reactive functional paradigm.

But Terms like `Type class morphisms` and some of the terms with #3 link like `monoids, functors, applicative functors, monads, morphisms, and improving values` are completely novice to me.

**Are these really related to Reactive functional programming?**

Please explain with JavaScript sample for those terms

Comment: They are relevant for functional programming, and they are relevant for reactive programming in Haskell. They are not so very important for what you call "FRP" in Javascript. Of course it's a good idea to learn them, but not necessary.

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia. I don't think these can be appropriately translated to JS.

Comment: If you can explain those terms atleast with some pseudo codes. It would be great. Terms are very difficult to dignose since am from php and javascript background i dont know how to relate with code. Kindly help

Comment: Well just learn Haskell (it's not that hard) *if* you want to understand those

Comment: Sure will learn it out